# Best practice for request/response from multiple clients to MSMQ server

Tags: .net, msmq

I want to create an application where multiple clients (say, C1, C2, C3) will send requests via MSMQ to a server (say S1), then wait for responses sent via MSMQ by the server.

The server will process received requests asynchronously.

From what I've read so far, the most robust MSMQ configuration is "send remote / receive local", which means that the request queue should be located on the server S1, and there should be a separate response queue on each client (C1, C2, C3).

This leaves me with the problem of communicating to the server with each request the queue to which it should send the corresponding response.

It appears that I can do this by having each client set `Message.ResponseQueue` to an instance of the local queue it is using to receive responses.

When I do this, as far as I can see (with the proviso that I've only tested with client and server on the same machine), `Message.ResponseQueue` is, as expected, set to an appropriate `MessageQueue` instance when the message is received by the server.

My problem is that the server can't use that instance, as it is going to process requests asynchronously and not return the response until later.

Is the following a reasonable approach:

- Extract `Message.ResponseQueue.Path` from the message received by the server, and store it.
- Create a new `MessageQueue` instance using this path when it is time to return the response.

If so, do I need to dispose the `MessageQueue` instance referenced by `Message.ResponseQueue`?

Comment: Do you want to receive a response as soon as server is done processing the message? Or can your client send a message and then poll the server later time to get stored responses? In short, two way or one way communication?

Comment: No polling: the client should get the response as soon as it is available.